# GCD of Polynomials over $Z_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to find the gcd of $f(x) = x^4 + 5x + 1$ and $g(x) = x^2 - 1$ over the field $Z_7$

Here is my attempt:

$x^4 + 5x + 1 = (x^2+1)(x^2-1) + 5x + 2$

$x^2-1 = (1/5x - 2/25)(5x + 2) + 29/25$

But this does not seem correct to me.

Comment: You have divided $x^2+1$ by $5x+2$ in the second line...

Comment: "The" gcd, with almost no calculation, is $x-1$. If you want to use the Euclidean Algorithm, we cannot have fractions. Instead of $1/5$, assuming it is correct, we need the multiplicative inverse of $5$ in the field. This is $3$.

Comment: Note that you can safely make $5x+2$ monic by multiplying by a constant: $3(5x+2)=x+6=x-1$ which is much easier to divide by than $5x+2$. In any event $5x+2=5x-5=5(x-1)$, so $x^2-1=(5x+2)(3x+3)+0.$ Don't use fraction notation in modular arithmetic - its not good.

Comment: For example, $4/25=4/4=1$ in $\mathbb Z_7$. Using fraction notation can cause a lot of problems if you aren't careful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** 
$f(1)=0$ and $g(1)=0$ in $\mathbb Z_7$. So $1$ is a root of both. So , $gcd=(x-1)$.